# AJAX-PHP Combination: $.post Checkbox value to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I'm trying for days to solve this problem, but with no results so far...
All I want to do is to POST checkbox value to php when the user check or uncheck it.

**form.php:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['box'])) {
echo $_POST['box'];
} ?>
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.box').on('change', function(event) { 
  var checkbox = $(event.target);
  var isChecked = $(checkbox).is(':checked');
  $.post('/form.php', {id: checkbox.attr('id'), value: isChecked});
 });
}); 
</script> //Credit cymen
```

**Form:**

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">

<input id="box" class="box" name="box" type="checkbox" value="YESSSSSS!" />
<input id="box" class="box" name="box" type="checkbox" value="YESSSSSS!" />

</form>
```

(*) I get nothing on `$_POST['box']`

Comment: firstly your id's for each checkbox must be unique!

Comment: validate your html ... **id must be unique**

Comment: but I have a lot of them. How can php know which one I refer to?

Comment: @wizard Generally speaking the `name` attribute of the input corresponds to the request parameter that contains its value when you post the form.

Comment: @wizard, the element `id` is never sent to the server, only its `name` and `value`. For what you're doing here, there's no need for an `id` because you're using the class name to select the checkboxes.

Comment: @MrCode How should it look?

Answer (score 3):

Your JavaScript is submitting this data to PHP:

```
 {id: checkbox.attr('id'), value: isChecked}
```

You have two pieces of data there: "id" and "value". You don't have a piece of data called "box", so `$_POST['box']` will not be populated.

Comment: Do you mean: `{id: checkbox.attr('box'), value: isChecked}`? try it - it doesn't work.

Comment: @wizard — No. You don't have `<input box="anything">` do you? And that would still submit `id` something and you are looking for `box` in the data. If you want to submit the `id` as `$_POST['box']` then `{box:...`.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST array that You sent to form.php is't look $_POST['box']. It looks like this:

```
array(2) {["id"]=>string(3) "box" ["value"]=> string(4) "true"}
```

So You can get to vars like thist $_POST['id'] or $_POST['value']. You're declaring vars in JS in this fragment: {id: checkbox.attr('id'), value: isChecked}.

It's good to check in PHP what You have in vars using var_dump, eg. var_dump($_POST).

Use Firebug plugin to FF, to debug AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

I would change to:

```
$.post('/form.php', {name: checkbox.attr('name'), checked: isChecked, value : checkbox.val()});
```

On the PHP side you will receive:

```
Array
(
    [name] => box
    [checked] => true
    [value] => YESSSSSS!
)
```

You can access the POST data like:

```
echo $_POST['name']; // box
echo $_POST['checked']; // true/false
echo $_POST['value']; // YESSSSSS!
```

It's important that you include the checkbox value in the POST request because that is your only way of identifying which checkbox was changed.

Comment: Unfortunately it still not working....though everything seems in the right place.